# wxPython -- how to use an installed font on Ubuntu

Tags: python, user-interface, fonts, wxpython

I have found references to how to pull a font installed to a Windows system, but I can't find or figure out how to do so on Ubuntu.  I'm using ubuntu 14.04, wxpython 3.0 and I have the font installed in usr/share/fonts/truetype.

I'm not worried about platform independence, this is a strictly personal project that will only be used on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? As far as I can tell, the FontEnumerator works on Ubuntu and let's you select and set any font installed on the system. You might check out that demo in the wxPython demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer - I recommend using the FontEnumerator widget. It allows you to select and set any font installed on your system. There is an example in the wxPython demo.

Here is a demo that uses the demo as its basis:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        e = wx.FontEnumerator()
        e.EnumerateFacenames()
        elist= e.GetFacenames()

        elist.sort()

        s1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Face names:")

        self.lb1 = wx.ListBox(self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (200, 250),
                              elist, wx.LB_SINGLE)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelect, id=self.lb1.GetId())

        self.txt = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Sample text...", (285, 50))

        row = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row.Add(s1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        row.Add(self.lb1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        row.Add(self.txt, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ADJUST_MINSIZE, 5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(row, 0, wx.ALL, 30)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.lb1.SetSelection(0)
        self.OnSelect(None)
        wx.FutureCall(300, self.SetTextSize)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetTextSize(self):
        self.txt.SetSize(self.txt.GetBestSize())

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnSelect(self, evt):
        face = self.lb1.GetStringSelection()
        font = wx.Font(28, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, face)
        self.txt.SetLabel(face)
        self.txt.SetFont(font)
        if wx.Platform == "__WXMAC__": self.Refresh()

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          title="wx.FontEnumerator Tutorial",
                          size=(800,600))
        panel = TestPanel(self)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

For further reference, see below:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/FontEnumerator.html
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/